# Why is tar-ing a folder containing some gzipped files as large as the unzipped files?

Tags: gzip, tar

Given the following folder structure (with the size in bytes in parenthesis):

```
- dir
  - f1.txt (1754)
  - f2.txt (9811)
```

When I run `gzip -r dir`, I get:

```
 - dir
   - f1.txt.gz (654)
   - f2.txt.gz (804)
```

Now when I do `tar -cf dir.tar dir` (where `dir` contains the **compressed** files), I expect the size of `dir.tar` to be roughly `654 + 804 = 1450`. But it turns out that it is 10240, which is the size of the `f1.txt + f2.txt`! Why???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's work through an example to confirm what you are seeing.

Here I have a directory, `x` , with two files.

```
# ls -l x
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3902 Jan 30 17:00 log1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7518 Jan 30 17:00 log.txt
```

Compress the files

```
# gzip -9v x/*
x/log1.txt:  90.6% -- replaced with x/log1.txt.gz
x/log.txt:   84.5% -- replaced with x/log.txt.gz
```

Confirm that compression has worked

```
# ls -l x
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  392 Jan 30 17:00 log1.txt.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1195 Jan 30 17:00 log.txt.gz
```

Put the files into a tar, `x.tar`

```
# tar cvf x.tar x
x/
x/log1.txt.gz
x/log.txt.gz
```

and check the resulting size. I got `10240` as well.

```
# ls -l x.tar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10240 Jan 31 09:02 x.tar
```

The reason is quite simple - the tar format works in fixed block sizes, so there will be a lot of padding will NULL bytes.  See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Blocking.html) for the gory details. For small file sizes like this these padding bytes will dominate. If you look at a hex dump of this tar file it contains mostly NULL padding bytes.

This is why it is better to put the uncompressed version of the files into the tar, then compress that.

Here is an example.

Put the uncompressed files into `x.tar`

```
# ls -l x
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3902 Jan 30 17:00 log1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7518 Jan 30 17:00 log.txt

# tar cvf x.tar x
x/
x/log1.txt
x/log.txt

# ls -l x.tar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 20480 Jan 31 09:06 x.tar
```

Now compress the tar file. `1761` bytes is a lot better.

```
# gzip -9v x.tar
x.tar:   91.7% -- replaced with x.tar.gz

# ls -l x.tar.gz 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1761 Jan 31 09:06 x.tar.gz
```

Comment: "This is why it is better to put the uncompressed version of the files into the tar, then compress that." I've always wonder why but now I know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you generate tar file for both original and compressed files. To make it sure, you can list the tar file contents.

```
tar -tf dir.tar.gz
```

Simply you can tar + gzip directory as bellow:

```
tar -zcvf dir.tar.gz dir/
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Running `tar -tf` yields:

```
dir
dir/f1.txt.gz
dir/f2.txt.gz
```

Comment: It seems you must verify the tar file info related to your source files.